# Geocoding in bilingual areas

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Recently, Google officially [announced](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.de/2014/11/localization-of-street-addresses-in.html) its Geocoding API was now "favouring the local language" if the user's language was using the same alphabet as the local one.

This has caused some trouble, however.

In Ukraine, Russian street names are widely used, even by official government bodies. Due to the recent change, Russian street names can no longer be retrieved - not in areas, where Russian is a regional, semi-official language and not even in Crimea, where Russian names are now the de-facto main official names after the peninsula's annexation by Russia. The following request will give back the Ukrainian name even when I specifically want the Russian one: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Lenina%20St,%20Sevastopol&language=ru

Google Maps' Russian language layer still renders city names in Russian, but streets and most POIs will not get localized anymore. In Belarus, the situation is similar, although Russian is a fully official language there. Geocoding still works, but Google Maps is not displaying Russian names any longer on its Russian map layer.

Is there any work-around for this?

Answer (score 0):

The same issue can be seen [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7651). It seems it may be just due to a lack of data/information, in which case you can try to get Google Maps updated using the [MapMaker](http://www.google.com/mapmaker). I'm not sure how things were prior to the localization update, but if the information was previously available, perhaps you can file a ticket in the issue tracker to change the local languages to be more appropriate?